# BASH - Removing carriage return append next line, but not everytime

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I made a query from an Oracle SQL DB but for some reason the resulting file gets trimmed like this:

```
52358288288673;01-06-2013 00:00:04;/john/wayne/subm
it;0,22;889;30008;1201;
51258186442676;01-06-2013 00:00:18;/john//wayne/finding/
sss/zone;0,22;889;30008;1531;
55344684156846;01-06-2013 00:00:31;/john/wayne/nosu
chthing;0,22;889;30008;1901;
536511965579726;01-06-2013 00:00:48;/john/wayne/cha
rs/get;0,22;889;30008;1504;
```

I'm on OSX and I have tried using tr, sed, awk and perl from other questions I have seen here but still none of them have worked or if I remove all carriage returns then I end up with all the lines together.

I need a way to read the file and find every line that doesn't have a ; at the end and append the next line.

```
52358288288673;01-06-2013 00:00:04;/john/wayne/submit;0,22;889;30008;1201;
51251234256762;01-06-2013 00:00:18;/john//wayne/finding/sss/zone;0,22;889;30008;1531;
55344684156846;01-06-2013 00:00:31;/john/wayne/nosuchthing;0,22;889;30008;1901;
53651196579726;01-06-2013 00:00:48;/john/wayne/chars/get;0,22;889;30008;1504;
```

I have tried stuff like:

```
cat file.txt | sed "s/$(printf '\r')\$//"
cat file.txt | tr ';$\n' '\n'
cat file.txt | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'
cat file.txt | sed ^'s/;$//g'
```

But nothing gets the job done. The file had more trash in it which I have removed, but I cannot find a way to solve this one. I'm thinking that when a line doesn't have a ; at the end, then-> remove carriage return. But I guess a one-liner is asking too much? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This awk script searches for NOT (!) the ; at end of line, if found it prints (with no newline), then uses `next` to go to the next line. If not found it simply prints the line.

```
awk '!/;$/ {printf;next}1' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print $0} FNR%2==0 {printf("\n");}' infile > outfile
```

Comment: Close, but I get the carriage return at the end of the second line: it;0,22;889;30008;1201;

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (It is pretty much self-explanatory)

```
while read line 
do 
  if [ `echo $line | grep ';$' | wc -l` -eq 0 ] ; then
        echo $line | sed 's|\n||g' >> $outputfile
  else
        echo $line >> $outputfile
  fi
done < $inputfile
```

Comment: `if echo "$line" | grep -qv ';$'; then` would be much simpler.